# Creating a server database for my mobile app data sync

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I'm new to mobile platform development and i want my mobile database created in sqlite by phonegap, to sync with a  server database. can any of you explain me basic steps of creating a server and a database in it (and the tools for that). I'm using eclipse and don't know which plugins to download for server creation. also if there is any other simple way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service that will point to your server database you can use [WEBAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)  via app you can make a [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to this service passing data to and fro in json format. You can find sql lite plugin [here](https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android)

Comment: hey, thnk u bt i have already created a database in my mobile device, i jus need to create a server db, and what are your takes on php over (dot)net.?